# Action is unreachable after submitting a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following problem (I spend many hours looking for a solution).

The ‘Create’ button has a click event which calls the ‘Test’ action on the ‘Home’ controller.

All works fine.

When I hit the ‘Save’ button, to submit the form, that works fine to.

But after I have submitted the form, my ‘Create’ button stops working. The ‘Create’ button does have the click event, but the ‘Test’ action is unreachable?

index.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#create").click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 traditional: true,
                 url: 'Home/Test',
                 dataType: "html",
                 success: function (data) {
                    alert('Succes!')
                 },
                 error: function () {
                     alert('A problem ocurred!!');
                 }
             });

         });
     });
</script>

 <input id="create" type="button" value="Create" />
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveForm", "Home"))
  {
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  }
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Test() 
    {
        return Content("Test result");
    }

    public ActionResult SaveForm()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick suggestion I have is move your script below the rest of your html.  More about good development practice than a fix.

Answer (score 1):

All of your actions are GET only. Either add `[HttpPost]` (POST only) or `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post, HttpVerbs.Get)]` (GET or POST) attributes to your POST actions.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test() 
{
    return Content("Test result");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveForm()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: Hi jrummell, thank you for your reaction. I have added the [HttpPost], and I tried the [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post, HttpVerbs.Get)] you suggested, but it did not work. Is it possible that i do someting wrong in the way I use Html.BeginForm("SaveForm", "Home")?

Comment: Thank you for your comment jrummell, eventually I used Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm, added the [HttpPost] attributes to my actions and I used the RedirectToAction("Index") instead of PartialView. That solved my problem. Thanks again for your tips!

Answer (score 0):

Theres 2 problems:

1) you dont have [HttpPost] above your methods

2) You are not sending any data to your controller

add an id to your form by using an anonymous class:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveForm", "Home", new {id = "testform"}))
```

then rewrite the ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#create").click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 data: $("#testform").serialize();
                 url: 'Home/Test',
                 dataType: "html",
                 success: function (data) {
                    alert('Succes!')
                 },
                 error: function () {
                     alert('A problem ocurred!!');
                 }
             });

         });
     });
</script>
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment Anthony, eventually I used Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm, added the [HttpPost] attributes to my actions and I used the RedirectToAction("Index") instead of PartialView. That solved my problem. Thanks again for your tips!

Answer (score 0):

To create an entity, you have to submit your data to server, either by post back or ajax as in your case. Now there are some contradictions in your code :)

```
1. Why are you calling one action as form action and another through
   ajax? Because since your button will post back, your ajax call won't
   fire the success and error handlers. To solve this either use <button> or
```

`$("#create").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();//Some code});`

```
2. If you want to use ajax, write it like this. Also write [HttpPost] on 
   your action. This indicates that this action can be called by post requests.
   This is a required step, whether or not you are using ajax.
```

I hope this solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment gauravvgat, eventually I used Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm, added the [HttpPost] attributes to my actions and I used the RedirectToAction("Index") instead of PartialView. That solved my problem. Thanks again for your tips!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm, added the [HttpPost] attributes to my actions and I used the RedirectToAction("Index") instead of PartialView. That solved my problem. Thanks again for your tips!